# How many tags can you name for "windows-batch"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655468/enosh) managed to figure out several:

[batch](/questions/tagged/batch) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) [bat](/questions/tagged/bat) [dos-batch](/questions/tagged/dos-batch) [winbatch](/questions/tagged/winbatch)

The only other one I can think of is [.bat](/questions/tagged/.bat).

Aside from [batch], I'd suggest them all as synonyms for [batch-file] if I had enough points. Since I don't, does somebody else want to do it?

Comment: @ColeJohnson What "canonical answer" are you seeking? All of these synonyms have already been approved. Is there some other information or discussion that you're seeking?

Comment: @animuson I clicked the wrong one. I meant to click "Reward existing answer" :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the exception of `batch`, I've added these to the [synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/synonyms). People can go vote for them as they see fit.